# How to read data from a .yaml file in Google Colab

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, yaml, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to read data from a `.yaml` file which is on my local computer. However, when I import the file and print the data, it comes in a single line. Screenshot for reference on the output is here:

[image]

However, I was able to read the data successfully, in the desired dictionary format by using Jupiter notebook. Screenshot for reference is here

[image]

How can I read the data in line by line dictionary format in Colab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=BaCkyg5CV5jF),

> `files.upload` returns a dictionary of the files which were uploaded.

So you need to do

```
uploaded = files.upload()
for key, value in uploaded.items():
  data = yaml.load(value)
  print(key)  # prints the file name
  print(data) # prints the loaded data
```

Comment: Thank You, this worked! However the entire output on printing 'data' is still shown in one line, making it hard to understand. Is there a way to put a '/n' at every ',' value in the dictionary? Similar to the Jupyter screenshot attached in the main Question?

Comment: I don't really know how Jupyter achieves it, obviously it is not the default behavior of Python's `print()`. They either substitute the print function or do post processing on its output, none of which is simply reproducable. Since you're using YAML anyway, why don't you `print(yaml.dump(data))`?

Comment: You're right. It's just that `print(yaml.dump(data))` produces a string, so can't be used as a dict. But is does help to understand the data better. Thanks again :)

Comment: After printing, you can still use `data` as dict, I don't really understand what you're saying here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data = yaml.load(data["ipl_match.yaml"])
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked too! However the entire output on printing 'data' is still shown in one line, making it hard to understand. Is there a way to put a '/n' at every ',' value in the dictionary? Similar to the Jupyter screenshot attached in the main Question?

Comment: This code will render json with collapsible headings. https://gist.github.com/korakot/072f1ea70d3c3267ff2c64b61d78c89c

Comment: I will check this out! Thank You :)